# How do we give directions in space?

Tags: navigation

If I'm on a life boat, in the middle of the ocean, radioing another ship to come pick me up - I'd say something like "I'm 40 kilometers directly east of you."

In space, it's not that easy. How do you give a direction?

Comment: By the distance to the Neutral Zone :-) .  (the point is that the StarTrek universe was really bad at identifying orientations and locations)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I have always wondered that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define an agreed standard for orientation of axis and origin.

What co-ordinate system you choose as a standard depends on your purpose.

Here are some examples and links : [Celestial coordinate systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celestial_coordinate_system).

Typical reference points are defined using very distant objects whose position can be measured accurately ( typically quasars ).

Comment: Within solar system, adding some local objects like Earth Venus and Mars relative to your distant objects should increase accuracy greatly.